# Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my encryption code?

Tags: java, encryption

My code is supposed to get the text from a text document and encrypt it by incrementing each character by 1. I want the output to be: **q b t t x** (the encryption of passw.) But instead it just outputs: **q** Anyone know how to fix this?
Also the text document that holds what should be encrypted contains the text "passw."

```
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptionMain {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    File file = new File("c:\\Visual Basic Sign in\\password.txt");
    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String text = null;

        // repeat until all lines is read
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            contents.append(text)
                    .append(System.getProperty(
                            "line.separator"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    int first = 0, second = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++)
    {
    char[] arr = new char[7];
    contents.getChars(first, second, arr, 0); // get chars 0,1 to get 1st char
    char ch = arr[i];
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch < 'Z') ch++; 
        else if (ch == 'Z') ch = 'A'; 
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch < 'z') ch++; 
        else if (ch == 'z') ch = 'a'; 
    // show encrypted contents here
    System.out.println(ch);
    first++;
    second++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: You should **hash** passwords.  And, **do not invent your own crypto**.  Creating secure encryption algorithms is _hard_.

Comment: I've been staring at my code for the past 1 1/2 hours and still haven't found it. So I figured one of you guys could figure it out. Sorry if I'm convicting a hated action on this website because I'm pretty new.

Comment: You have already pasted your code in another question, and what I said in a comment still holds: if you want to encrypt, use _byte arrays_. Never read as text.

Comment: I'm not really trying to make it "secure" I just want to do it to learn more about this field.

Comment: Do not stare at the code. It is not a picture. Debug it. Check at several step which are the values of the variables, and compare these to the expected values.

Comment: Although OP certainly needs to work on his own debugging skills rather than asking others to do it, there's no need to jump on him for his attempt at encryption. This is clearly for practice/learning (possibly homework, possibly not), not production code for a commercial app. The question is about an error in the program logic, not whether it's secure encryption.

Comment: At least, I hope not.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard the problem here is that (I'll say it again and again) the file is read as text; when you encrypt, you should not do that since the result will be dependent, among oter things, on the character set you are using _and_ on line endings.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yes you are right, I was not trying to make a secure encryption or ask weather or not it was secure. Because I think anyone would know incrementing a character by 1 wont help anything related to security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contents.getChars(first, second, arr, 0);
char ch = arr[i];
```

This copies a character from `contents` into `arr[0]` not `arr[i]`. So changing the second line to `char ch = arr[0];` should work. But there are easier ways to access characters from a String. See 'charAt' or 'toCharArray'.

Comment: Oh my god you are a life saver! Thank you so much, and I will be sure to look into your other two suggestions! <3

Comment: +1 for telling what's wrong with existing code and giving (much) better alternatives.

Comment: You should accept the life-saving answer.